# IIS logging feature

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have ASP.NET pages deployed and I was told that it appears to be logging quite a bit on the server (Ex. post and get).  I am sure this is a feature on the IIS not with the pages.
The site interacts with other systems and use by a lot of users.

My questions are:
1. What does this mean?
2. Can I turn off this feature on the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Logging is a feature which you use to configure how IIS logs requests on the Web server.

2) Yes you can Disable logging from IIS by selecting Logging icon and disable from context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's frustrating that logging is turned on in IIS by default. If you don't know it's there, it's just filling up your web server with useless information.

However, the information in the log file is not useless if you know it is there.

If you have access to the web server, there are a couple of places that the log files might be saved in:

```
C:\WINNT\system32\LogFiles
C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1\exyymmdd.log
```

You can view the file contents in Notepad.

To get the exact log file name in IIS, right-click on the website, go to the Web Site tab, click on the Properties button, and go to the bottom of the pane. The filename is there.

There are choices of what kinds of data get logged. You may not need a lot of it. For example, the default log items like Date, Time and Client IP Address might be useful. Not so much Bytes Sent, Time Taken or Referrer, unless you are troubleshooting.